# variable component not updated Angular 7

Tags: angular, variables, post, subscribe

i have a variable component `idWizard` and into `ngOnInit` after post `http` is not updated. the new value is not present in variable after subscribe. the value is undefined.

```
    export class HeaderComponent {  
    @Input() idWizard: string;   
    ngOninit(){ var response = this.was.postWizardStart(wi);
     response.subscribe(res => { 

      this.idWizard = res.headers.get('idWizard');
       console.log("HEADER  ngOnInit 2 OK 200 Server - Idwizard is: " + 
        this.idWizard);
         this.ref.markForCheck()
         console.log(this.idWizard);
         this.emitflag = true;

        },  

         err  => {
           console.log(err);
          });

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: this.idWizard = res.headers.get('idWizard'); in this statement what is res.headers?

Comment: res is the response from post http, this.idWizard is updated but only in subscribe, if i call this.idWizard for ex, in ngDoCheck this.idWizard is undefined . why?

Comment: can I see your ngDoCheck method?

Comment: ngDoCheck(idWizard){

      this.valueChanged.emit(idWizard);

  }

Answer (score 0):

You got a couple of things wrong. First you need to implement `OnInit` and then you have to write properly the method name`ngOnInit()` (you got an lowercase 'i' where it goes an uppercase 'I'). I think that method is never running.

You should get something like this:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() idWizard: string;   
    ngOnInit(){
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: the value of idWizard out of subsribe function is undefined ... why?

Comment: Are you running another function outside ngOnInit()?

Comment: So, the parent component is the one which receives undefined, not the header component with the ngOnInit method right?

Comment: when i try this into subscribe. this.valuechanged.emit(this.idWizard) the emit function not call a parent code. so, if i try to call this.idWizard out subscribe is undefined. if you want ther're two issue: 1.the emit function not working into ngOnInit method and out of subscribe variable component is not updated. thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this it might work

you can call ngDoCheck() inside ngOnit and pass the idWizard value as method argument like this ngDoChcek(this.idWizard).

Comment: i cannot pass paramter to ngDoCheck .  it's wthout parameter .but i try this:  ngDoCheck(){

     this.valueChanged.emit(this.idWizard);

 }

Comment: what are you trying to do idwizard value? I may have better solution than ngDoCheck

Comment: i'm trying with ngDoCheck but the value is undefined out subscribe....always undefined.